# Get real devices dimensions even if the viewport meta tag is in the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to retrieve the real dimensions (w & h) of mobile devices.

For instance, if in my index.html I **remove** the viewport meta tag:

`<!--meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0" /-->`

on Nexus 6 the `window.innerWidth` is 981px. 
If I **add** viewport meta tag:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0" />`

the `window.innerWidth` get down to 412px of course.

I need viewport's benefits for my 'mobile UI' in the page, but as the same time I need to retrieve the real dimensions of the device.

e.g. the innerWidth is 412px but the real device width is 981px and I want to ask an image with width=981px instead 412px for a better quality.

There's a way to retrieve real devices dimensions with the viewport tag added inside the page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: The scale probably isn't set right, here's an example viewport meta tag with scale 1: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` this is for width only.

Comment: @RudieVisser I've edited the question adding the viewport I'm using

Comment: @Pierfrancesco I'm not sure why it returns 412, with the tag I'm using it's working fine on my own page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a 'pork-around' to retrieve the real devices dimensions before the viewport change them.

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var preMetaWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var preMetaHeigth = window.innerHeight;
  </script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<body>
    ...
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.screen.width` and `window.screen.height` to get the device dimensions regardless of the presence of `viewport` meta tag.

Comment: If the viewport is present in the page window.screen.width and window.innerWidth are the same. 
If the viewport is NOT in the page they are different. But I need to keep the viewport in the page. However thanks for sharing this solution

Comment: Your question was about getting the real device dimensions while view port meta tag is on. The answer is that you can use windows.screen.

*"There's a way to retrieve real devices dimensions with the viewport tag added inside the page?"*